# Erlang random:seed() undefined

Tags: random, erlang, undefined, seed

Every time I whant to get random seed, firstly i got "undefined", and then what i want.

```
1>random:seed(erlang:now()).
undefined
```

what's wrong?

another proof:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta2AC.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `random` module [stores the seed](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/random.erl#L85) value in the process dictionary using the `put` BIF. `put` returns the current value associated with the key (`random` module uses "random_seed"), so the first time you call `seed` there's no value associated with the key "random_seed" so it returns `undefined`, and on subsequent calls, it returns the current value, hence the values you're getting.

Example:

```
1> put(foo, "bar").
undefined
2> put(foo, "baz").
"bar"
```